# How to set up $(shell ) with GNU MCU Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, shell

I'm trying to get my work laptop build environment working on my home PC. 
(Working from home for a few months, you just guessed why).

Using GNU MCU Eclipse. I've installed the same version on my home machine as I installed in late 2018 on my work machine. The project I'm working on uses an external makefile to build for an ARM (SAM4L) target. Clearly there was a step that I did way back then that I've forgotten this time around.

I have the same build tools, toolchain, and Eclipse version installed on both machines (albeit in slightly different locations). On both machines, "where make.exe" and "where sh.exe" at the windows command prompt finds the executables in the Windows Build tools.

My work machine builds successfully, but my home machine gets stuck with $(shell ... ) calls within the makefile.

The first line that gives me trouble:

```
DATE := $(shell date +%Y%m%d)
```

The console output is:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, date +%Y%m%d, ...) failed.
make: Makefile:26: pipe: No error
```

Similar errors occur with subseqent calls to $(shell uname) e.g.:

```
os_type         ?= $(strip $(shell uname))

ifeq ($(os_type),windows32)
os              := Windows
```

gives the error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
make[1]: ../../../thirdparty/asf/sam/utils/make/Makefile.sam.in:105: pipe: No error
```

The only other difference is that my work machine has another installation of MinGW/msys providing a separate sh and make, but these aren't in my Windows path. Nevertheless it's possible these are being used by Eclipse, but I don't see how. I've spent most of the day trawling through the configuration on both machines (Project->properties), and I can't see a difference.

[Edit] - I Just confirmed that both installs call the Make that is in the Windows Build tools, and both are the same version. (and not the same as the other tools in the build-tools that are from a busybox build)

```
~/eclipse/GNU MCU Eclipse/Build Tools/2.11-20180428-1604/bin $ ./make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-w64-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Any guidance??

Answer (score 0):

OK, Easy when you see it.

I didn't have a `date` or `uname` command in my Build tools. Because the build tools are based on BusyBox i just needed to copy busybox.exe to date.exe and to uname.exe to provide the required functions. (also needed `test` command). Clearly I worked this out 18 months ago. I've written a howto doc for next time :-)   .

```
C:\...\GNU MCU Eclipse\Build Tools\2.11-20180428-1604\bin>sh -c "cp busybox.exe date.exe"
C:\...\GNU MCU Eclipse\Build Tools\2.11-20180428-1604\bin>sh -c "cp busybox.exe uname.exe"
C:\...\GNU MCU Eclipse\Build Tools\2.11-20180428-1604\bin>sh -c "cp busybox.exe test.exe"
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.